# Cannot read data from DATA USAGE screen of device on button click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-intentservice, android-settings

I am opening DATA USAGE screen on button click from my application, using the following Intent:-

Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);

Now I want to read the data usage of a particular application, say YouTube, and print the same on an EditText in my application. Can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe over https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html

Comment: Fortunately, this is not generally possible. Apps cannot spy on the UI of other apps, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare...I agree with your answer, but what if my app's requirement is that I print data usage of a particular app, from Settings to my app? In this case, can't I read those data?